# C# Application Insights - multiple instances of TelemetryClient

Tags: c#, azure, logging, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I would like to log Application Insights telemetry data to both my own account and a client's account.

Is there any issue with using multiple instances of TelemetryClient to log the same data to two different Application Insights instrumentation keys? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can specify InstrumentationKey either on TelemetryClient level:

```
    this.Client = new TelemetryClient();
    this.Client.InstrumentationKey = "<your ikey>";
```

Or directly on individual item level:

```
    public void ModifyItem(ITelemetry item)
    {
        // Replace ikey
        item.Context.InstrumentationKey = this.ikey;
    }
```

If you are sending to different ikeys auto-collected data then you can modify instrumentation key either in TelemetryInitializer or even direct data yourself using TelemetryProcessor.

Comment: But does that mean I can send the same data to two different App Insights buckets?

Comment: Yes, you can send data to different AI resources.